# Angular is undefined Error with karma-jasmin testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am new to Testing using Karma-jasmine to run the test but getting error.

My karma.conf.js

```
files: [
  'test/*Spec.js',
  'app/js/*.js'
],
```

This error is Showing in command line

> ```
> Chrome 39.0.2171 (Windows 7) ERROR
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
>   at D:/Test_Samples/WebContent/MyTest/app/js/angular-route.js:24
>
>
> Firefox 34.0.0 (Windows 7) ERROR
>   TypeError: angular is undefined
>   at D:/Test_Samples/WebContent/MyTest/app/js/angular-route.js:24
>
>
> IE 8.0.0 (Windows 7) ERROR
>   'undefined' is null or not an object
>   at D:/Test_Samples/WebContent/MyTest/app/js/angular-route.js:24
> ```

angular-route.js:24

```
/* global -ngRouteModule */
var ngRouteModule = angular.module('ngRoute', ['ng']).provider('$route', $RouteProvider),
    $routeMinErr = angular.$$minErr('ngRoute');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to import angular and angular-stuff before your tests.
This is an example of configuration I'm using:

```
files: [
    {pattern: 'src/main/webapp/static/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js', watch: false},
    {pattern: 'src/main/webapp/static/libs/angular/angular.js', watch: false},
    {pattern: 'src/main/webapp/static/libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.js', watch: false},
    {pattern: 'src/main/webapp/static/libs/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', watch: false},
    {pattern: 'src/main/webapp/static/libs/angular-ngkit/js/ngkit.js', watch: false},
    'src/main/webapp/static/templates/angular/*.html',
    'src/main/webapp/static/js/angular/**/*.js',
    'src/test/js/spec/angular/*.js'
 ],
```

It's a best practice to avoid the watching of the libraries (`watch: false`), since those files won't change during the development!

It's also important to define the "`basePath`" property, since all the paths will be resolved using that root!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference angular.js file before any other angular file. 
Make sure to check your config file against the config file that you get when you install karma.  Refer to this webpage  for details. http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html